# Remove Windows 8 Nag (which executable to delete?)

Tags: windows-8, denial-of-service

I'm currently experiencing a Windows 8 DoS. When this nag ribbon is open, I cannot use the machine:

[image: Windows 8 DoS]

I've tried closing the ribbon with <kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, and a few others that used to close programs. I can bring up task manager, but I can't do anything with it.

I know I can force it to go away with a hard shutdown, but I don't like to do it because it could leave the filesystem in an inconsistent state. Also, it seems to come back on a regular basis so its not a good long-term solution.

What executable is producing the nag? I would like to delete it if possible.

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-update-to-windows-8-1-for-free-notification-in-windows-8-store/)?

Comment: Yes this is a duplicate, please close this. My apologies, I know better than that.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is caused by Windows Update KB2885699, you can either uninstall the update or disable notification via the registry.

If you don't prefer to uninstall, open powershell as administrator and run snip to set the `UpgradeAvailable` from 1 to 0

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\UpgradeNotification' -Name UpgradeAvailable -Value 0
#
```